# DataInputStream class Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, java, datainputstream

I want to know what is the Java DataInputStream class equivalent in C#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255):

```
var reader = new BinaryReader(myStream);
var value = reader.ReadInt32();
```

Answer (score -2):

there's no direct equivalent; but if you want to read data from console input, you can use Console.Read(), Console.ReadKey() or Console.ReadLine()

.NET Console Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz3fhfz1.aspx

If you want to read data from other sources, use an appropriate object that inherits from the [System.IO.Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) class. There's FileStream, MemoryStream, NetworkStream, etc.